Headphone Amp design explanation
This is a Rode AI-1 headphone amp / sound card, all credit to EEVblog to provide this teardown picture.
I am quite certain that "U1" is a TI RC4580 double op amp chip (datasheet). Looking at the datasheet it should be straightforward - one of these chips for each channel of the headphone. However these big "transistors" (I'm guessing) Q9, Q13, Q2 and Q6 are confusing me.
Looking from the jack output (bottom) there is a low-pass filter (big resistor "3R90"+cap) with a trace towards the U1; great, makes sense. But this trace is shared by a resistor going to one of these big transistors(?), which in turn (looking at Q6) is connected to "Q3" and another unnamed 3-leg component.
I am thinking these might be providing the bulk of the power instead of the op amp "U1", but I cannot see how that is. Also all these "Q_" devices might not all be transistors.
What's going on? Since it is this discrete I thought someone might be able to explain the mechanics here.
I have a unit on hand, but haven't opened it yet. I can of course check if there is a another op amp on the other side of the PCB.


